# Detail View won't show up when clicking from TableView Row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I've got an XCode iPHone project setup with the following:

My App Delegate creates a dynamic tabBarController and adds two view controllers to it. One of them contains a TableView.

From that TableView, I want the user to be able to click the Blue arrow button on each item and get more details about it. It's a pretty standard thing... here's the code I have to do that:

```
-(void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

        if (self.switchView == nil) {
            SwitchViewController *viewController = [[SwitchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SwitchViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            self.switchView = viewController;
            [viewController release];       
        }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.switchView animated:YES];
    self.switchView.title = @"Test Title";

}
```

Right now, my SwitchViewController is nothing but a blank view with a button on it. **When the user clicks the blue button, nothing happens.** I can put a breakpoint in and see all the code being executed, but the iPhone screen simply doesn't change.

Any tips? I'm sure this is something basic, as I'm pretty new to iOS development.

Thanks in advance!

R

Comment: Have you checked that navigationController is not nil? You have not mentioned any UINavigationControllers in your hierarchy...

Comment: Also check `viewController` to make sure that it's being instantiated properly from the NIB.

Comment: @Vladimir - I didn't specifically setup a "navigationController" I had just assumed that my current view *was* the nav controller. The tableview page where this code exists is inherited from UITableViewController. Know of an article that provides more details on an actual navigationController setup?

Comment: @kubi - What indications would I have that it isn't being setup properly? When I break at that point, the viewController object has a value and I can expand it and see my button, etc.

Comment: @Chu - That's exactly what I would check. As for the navigation controller, open a navigation-based iOS project to see how Apple's default templates set up the navigation controller. That's a great start.

Comment: @Chu, for a start create a project from a navigation based app template to see the general structure.

Comment: It is indeed nil... does the nav controller go in my app delegate or does it go in my page that has the table view controller in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer to Vladmir's question in the comments it's clear you don't have a UINavigationController initialized.  So try something like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];
```

Then add navController to your tabBarController instead of the tableViewController.